# FP vs FN for Malware detection

Tags: malware

I have been working on Random Forest Classifier to detect .exe files as Malware and benign. According to me False Negative in my model should be low because they are more harmful but in some blogs online, it is mentioned that False positive are more harmful in malware detection than a false negative. I was wondering what is the reason behind this.

Comment: I wouldn't say that's true in all cases. It also depends how the security product is configured. Imagine the case however if the product caused a FP on Services.exe for example? It could delete the file, maybe it would kill the process.  As it's a critical process that would bugcheck the computer for a start.  Deleting the Service Control Manager exe would also cause a host of problems. Deleting a users document they had worked on for the last x hours wouldn't go down too well either so it depends really.  If you take the line of "first do no harm" that could apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your malware detection software/anti-virus produces too many false positives, it will flag many useful applications as malware and users will, rightfully, get annoyed. Sooner or later, the users will either turn off or remove the malware protection completely or get used to ignoring and blindly clicking through any warning that the antivirus raises. The result will inevitably be that in the end, even blatantly malicious files will end up being executed by the users.

Yes, false negatives are harmful too, but having a few false negatives is better than detecting every malicious file (which isn't even really possible) but still having every single malware get through just because the user simply ignores the anti-virus. Additionally, in case a file is borderline suspicious, it can be sent to the anti-virus firm for further analysis and so new malware will be detected and its signatures added to the malware detection engine. However, if false positives lead to users turning off the protection, many malicious files will never be detected or will take a much longer time to get detected, confirmed as malicious and added to the signature database.